Bluetooth Connection Issue on HP Computer with Intel Killer Wi-Fi 6E AX1675 Network Adapter on Ubuntu
I am facing an issue with my HP computer running Ubuntu. I have installed an Intel Killer Wi-Fi 6E AX1675 network adapter (PCIe – 802.11ax with Bluetooth 5.3).
Problem:
I can connect to Wi-Fi without issues, but I'm having trouble with the Bluetooth functionality. Specifically:
The Bluetooth toggle switch does not work. It shows "No Bluetooth found. Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth", even though I have a built-in Bluetooth adapter. I have tried pairing my AirPods (Bluetooth is on), but the system still does not recognize any Bluetooth device.
What I’ve Tried:
I checked my wired headset with a dongle, and it works fine. However, I still get the message that no Bluetooth is available and can't toggle it on/off.
I would like to use wireless Bluetooth, and any assistance with resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!
